# Failed to load and parse manifest in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda

i'm trying to setup CUDA in VS2008 with cuda toolkit 4.1. I wrote simple program to print Hello World. I'm not able to compile this simple program. VS is giving me following error

`>Embedding manifest...
1>.\Debug\stream.exe.intermediate.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\myName\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\stream\stream\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>stream - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The manifest file is either not being generated at all, or Visual Studio looks for it in the wrong place. Check that the name and path for the manifest file matches between `Solution Properties | Linker | Manifest File` and `Solution | Properties | Manifest Tool`. You might also be able to temporarily work around the issue by turning off `Solution | Properties | Manifest Tool | Input and Output | Embed Manifest`, though that might cause trouble running the app.

Comment: I turned off manifest process but then it is not able to launch appname.exe file...

Comment: Have you checked your build log for any other clues to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new CUDA project from scratch. This works in Visual Studio 2010 with CUDA 4.1:

- Open Visual Studio
- Select `File | New | Project | Win32 Console Application`. No changes needed in the application settings.
- Right click the project in the solution. Select `Build Customizations`
- Check the box for CUDA 4.1 target
- Right click the project and select `Add | New Item | NVIDIA | CUDA | CUDA C/C++ file`
- Right click the project and select `Properties`
- In `Configuration Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies`, add `cudart.lib`
- Compile